# input type number can we stop editable and use drop/down for change value

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<input type="number" class="textbox" id="id_instant_book" onkeyup="instant_book_set()" value="<?php echo $listing['min_instant_book_percent'];?>" min="<?php echo $listing['min_instant_book_percent'];?>" max="100"name="id_instant_book"  style="display: none">
```

i dont want to give user to edit but he can use drop down ( point is i dont want to give user to use as textbox ) dont tell me use readonly becouse i want change value by using drop down provided by input type number.

Comment: Then use "Answer my own question" and please put down the answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer just add `onkeydown="return false"` so it will stop user to enter data but user can use drop/down for change there value.